# Iterate through array of hashes in ANT script

Tags: arrays, loops, foreach, ant, ant-contrib

I am working on some automation using Jenkins, where I have the schema and DB details stored like

`[schema1:db1, schema2:db2]` stored in a ANT property `${schemaValue}`

```
<propertycopy name="schemaValue" from="${SchemaVariable}"/>
```

Now I am trying to loop through this array of hashes to execute the connection,
I have tried with

```
        <for param="theparam" list="${schemaValue}">
            <sequential>
                <echo message="param: @{theparam}"/>
            </sequential>
        </for>
```

But this considers  `${schemaValue}` as String and not an array,

Help on this.

**EDIT**

As suggested by @AR.3, I have tried with

```
<propertyregex override="yes" property="paramValue" input="@{theparam}" regexp=".+:([^\]]+)]?" replace="\1"/>
<echo message="paramValue: ${paramValue}"/>
<propertyregex override="yes" property="paramKey" input="@{theparam}" regexp="[?([^\[]+):]" replace="\1"/>
<echo message="paramKey: ${paramKey}"/>
```

${paramValue} gives me db1 and db2 correctly

${paramKey} throws me error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of an array in Ant in the strict sense that exists in standard programming languages. The [`for`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html) loop will simply iterate over elements of a string delimited by a delimiter (the default delimiter is `,`). In your case, it also looks more like a map or a list of key-value pairs.

If the expected behavior is to print the values in the map (`db1` and `db2`), an additional step involving a regular expression replacement can be used:

```
<for param="theparam" list="${schemaValue}">
    <sequential>
        <propertyregex override="yes"
              property="paramValue"  input="@{theparam}"
              regexp=".+:([^\]]+)]?" replace="\1"/>
        <echo message="param: ${paramValue}"/>
    </sequential>
</for>
```

So originally, the echoed values contained in `theparam` will be `[schema1:db1` and `schema2:db2]`. The pattern `.+:([^\]]+)]?` will match against such values, by matching against:

1. one or more characters,
2. followed by a `:`,
3. followed by non-`]` characters,
4. followed by zero or one `]`.

The `propertyregex` will put the value of the first group, i.e. the one matched by `([^\]]+)` in a property `paramValue`. This will be in fact the value after the colon.

Running it should print:

```
[echo] param: db1
[echo] param: db2
```

**EDIT:**

To get the key instead, you can use the following regex:

```
<propertyregex override="yes" property="paramKey"
               input="@{theparam}" regexp="\[?([^\[]+):[^\]]+]?" replace="\1"/>
```

Comment: - Is it possible to get values like schema1 : db1 and then sch2ma2 : db2. Because here I receive dynamic schema names with database name.

Comment: @Jasmine Yes, just modify the above regex to your needs. In this case you can try `[?([^\[]+:[^\]]+)]?`.

Comment: I have tried with "([^\[]+:)" to find the key ${paramKey} but it is not rendering as expected.

Comment: You may have to escape the opening backet with a backslash. And you also need to match the entire key-value, with the parentheses around the key that precedes the colon. Try what I mentioned in the answer but with `[?([^\[]+):[^\]]+]?`.

Comment: Thank you. but still i am not able to fetch the correct key. Please see my EDIT portion above and guide me for ${paramKey}

Comment: @Jasmine Updated my answer. You should use the regex I included in my last comment, except that the first bracket should be escaped.